# Reload children Tab in two nested Tab React Native

Tags: react-native

My router :

```
const TabRoot = createBottomTabNavigator({
    TabMarket: TabMarket,
    Favorite: Favorite,
    Noti: Noti,
    News: News,
    User: User
}

const TabMarket = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    USDT: MarketComponent,
    BTC: MarketComponent,
    ETH: MarketComponent,
    HT: MarketComponent
}
```

in screen Favorite I have button click navigate to tab USDT in TabMarket.
But when in tab BTC, comeback to Favorite. I click button it navigate to BTC again.
How to custom to alway navigate to USDT